# Issue with jquery and firefox `Security error" code: "1000`

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've a problem with this instruction in firefox:

```
$(".photo_data", div).val(url);
```

In chrome it works well, but in firefox generate this error:

```
Security error" code: "1000
[Break On This Error] 
a.call(this,o,x.val());if(r==null)r=""...,width:true,height:true,offset:true}, 
jquery.min.js (line 53
```

the variable url is a url like "http://nerto.it"

How can i do?

Comment: Use the unminified jQuery and check where the error is.

Comment: @luca can we do something like this $(".photo_data", div).val(url); , for divs we have use text right...

Comment: @luca , .vals are used for only input types rigt

Comment: Further to @Slaks comment, point your jQuery's script `src` to: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js` and, as he suggests, *look where the error is.* Incidentally, from my own use-cases, these 'error...in jquery.min.js' tend to suggest that I've either left in a closing curly brace `}`, or omitted a closing curly brace somewhere in my own code. I've never, *yet*, encountered a genuine error in the jquery library script itself.

Comment: ellooooow please post your markup.

Comment: @luca , i don't think there shouldn't be anything wrong with jquery libary , might be some issue in his markup

Comment: To everyone who is saying that the OP should be using `text()` or `html()` instead of `val()` you **may** be incorrect. It is impossible to be sure without seeing the actual code. If the OPs HTML is `<div><input type="text" class="photo_data" /></div>` then the use of `val()` is correct and using `text()` or `html()` is wrong. Most likely you are all correct, but you cannot be sure without seeing the actual related HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Using .val() is for setting the "value" attribute of <input> elements. Divs do not have value attributes, they contain text or html. You would will have success if you try:

```
$(".photo_data", div).text(url);
```

If you're trying to insert HTML into the div, you can try:

```
$(".photo_data", div).html(url);
```

Read this for more info: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` instead of `.val()` as you are using divs not inputs.

Answer (score 0):

luca can we do something like this $(".photo_data", div).val(url); , for divs we have use text right

if it is a div use .text

```
$(".photo_data").text(url);
```

or if it is input use

```
$(".photo_data").val(url);
```